# What personal pronoun should be used with the noun "sheep"?

Tags: pronouns, personal-pronouns

I would like to know what personal pronoun would be correct to use instead of  the word **"sheep**" in a sentence?

> It is a sheep.

or

> She is a sheep.

I'll try to explain myself in a better way. I know that when we speak about an animal, in general, we use the pronoun "It" : it is a dog for ex. but I read some were that "sheep" is an exception and has to be referred to as a "she" . But I can't find any confirmation to that.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to ask about the verb _to be_? It sounds like you are asking about [_pronouns_](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/pronoun.asp).

Comment: i"ll try to explain myself in a better way. I know that when we speak about an animal, in general, we use the verb "It" : it is a dog for ex. but I read some were that "sheep" is an exception and has to be referred to as a "she" . But I can't find any confirmation to that ...

Comment: You usually use he or it for a sheep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It* and *she* are [pronouns](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/pronoun.asp). As far as I know, the exception you have provided is inaccurate.

You may use either *it* or *she* with *sheep*, assuming the sheep is female.

> [Uses of the impersonal pronoun it](http://www.englishgrammar.org/impersonal-pronoun/)
>   It can also be used for small and domestic animals.
>
> - I love my dog. It is almost human.
> - I will not sell my cow because it yields 10 litres of milk every day.

So it is possible to say "It is a sheep."

You may refer to a sheep as *she*, especially if you have a close relationship with it. It is not uncommon for people who love their pets to refer to the pets as *he* or *she*. For example, suppose you have a pet sheep named *Dolly*. You happen to mention *Dolly* and a friend asks "Who is Dolly?" You might reply

> **She** is my pet sheep.

It is possible to call male sheep *rams* and female sheep *ewes*. But all sheep, regardless of gender, can be called *sheep*.